# Time before full counter with percent python

Tags: python, django, math

how to calculate based on timestamp and get the progress before the max full value?

```
def full_energy():
     time_now = 1666650096 #changes every update
     time_end = 1666679529 
     max_energy = 50 

     diff = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time_now) - datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time_end)
     secs = diff.total_seconds()
     ???

# expected output
# x/y (z)
# 25/50 (50%)
```

how to get the value of x and z based on this sample?

Comment: Seems like you need to know the start time to compute percent toward end time complete.  Needs more information.

Comment: basically i'm trying to find out is how close it is to max_energy. if time_now is now() and time_end is let's say in 15mins, z will be 50% 7.5mins after time_now. i'm probably constructing the def/function wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work.  You need to provide the start time to compute percent completed.  Not sure how you want the display to function:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

def full_energy(start, now, end):
    max_energy = 50
    percent = (now - start) / (end - start)
    current_energy = max_energy * percent
    # In a typical text console this will overwrite the same line
    print(f'\r{current_energy:.0f}/{max_energy} ({percent:.0%})', end='', flush=True)

start = datetime.now()
end = start + timedelta(seconds=10)

while (now := datetime.now()) <= end:
    time.sleep(.2)
    full_energy(start, now, end)
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for! told you my function is incorrect... i hate being so noob. thank Mark!